# Year on year growth rates for multiple columns basis unique ID & years in rows

Tags: r, data-manipulation, data-mining, generic-derivation

I have a data set where I have a unique proposal ID, application year & financial statement year. One proposal ID shall have one application year(t) & could have t-1 &(or) t-2 financial year statements. I have multiple columns for debt, equity, networth etc & want to have two columns for YOY growth -F1 & YOY growth-2.

dataset :

```
Proposal ID Application Year Financial statement year Net sales
P1          2019             2019                     100
P1          2019             2018                     120
P1          2019             2017                     130
```

Now basis each proposal ID I need additional columns on growth rates between financial statement years against my application year

desired output :

```
Proposal ID Application Year Financial statement year Net sales YOY - netsales-g1
P1          2019             2019                     100             (100-120)/120...
P1          2019             2018                     120
P1          2019             2017                     130
```

this same step I need to do for all columns I have.

What I want is a function -- for each proposal ID it estimates the YOY growth & take out the latest application date as the final row with columns as YOY growth for all numeric variables in dataset

Thank you in advance for the help! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure but is it what you need?

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)
data %>% arrange(Financial_Statement_Year) %>%
  mutate(Growth_Difference = Net_Sales - lag(Net_Sales)) %>%
  mutate(Growth_Rate = (Growth_Difference / Net_Sales) * 100)
```

| Proposal_ID | Application_Year | Financial_Statement_Year | Net_Sales | Growth_Difference | Growth_Rate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| P3 | 2019 | 2017 | 130 | NA | NA |
| P2 | 2019 | 2018 | 120 | -10 | -8.333 |
| P1 | 2019 | 2019 | 100 | -20 | -20.000 |

Comment: hey this is cool, how did you get the code to be published like that in SO?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help this link should be helpful for you

Answer (score 1):

This can be done use the `dplyr::lead()` formula in `mutate()`. The `jantior::clean_names()` is optional to make the code writing easier.

```
df %>% 
  janitor::clean_names() %>% 
  mutate(YoY_net_sales=(net_sales-lead(net_sales,n=1L))/lead(net_sales,n=1L))
```